# python selenium perfLoggingPrefs filtering

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

According to the [chromedriver documentation](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/capabilities) I should be able to turn off the events from the Page domain when logging performance. I've tried setting the perfLoggingPrefs but I still get the Page events.  Am I setting this correctly?

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
options.add_argument("--ignore-certificate-errors")
options.add_argument("--disable-single-click-autofill")
options.add_argument("--disable-autofill-keyboard-accessory-view[8]")
options.add_argument("--disable-full-form-autofill-ios")

options.headless = True
options.add_argument('--disable-gpu')

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME
caps['loggingPrefs'] = {
    'browser': 'ALL',
    'performance' : 'ALL',
    }
caps['perfLoggingPrefs'] = {
    'enableNetwork' : True,
    'enablePage' : False,
    'enableTimeline' : False
    }

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, desired_capabilities=caps)

###  connect to my site, do some actions then I call
perfs = driver.get_log('performance')
for row in perfs:
    print(perfs)
```

Output:

```
{'level': 'INFO', 'message': '{"message":{"method":"Network.loadingFinished","params":{"encodedDataLength":0,"requestId":"A9C189F82C9479C83512A78F9FF9F3EA","shouldReportCorbBlocking":false,"timestamp":3369761.457106}},"webview":"A7D8907A1D283AC9EC1B03BC3C786243"}', 'timestamp': 1552406406094}
{'level': 'INFO', 'message': '{"message":{"method":"Page.frameNavigated","params":{"frame":{"id":"A7D8907A1D283AC9EC1B03BC3C786243","loaderId":"A9C189F82C9479C83512A78F9FF9F3EA","mimeType":"text/plain","securityOrigin":"://","url":"data:,"}}},"webview":"A7D8907A1D283AC9EC1B03BC3C786243"}', 'timestamp': 1552406406094}
{'level': 'INFO', 'message': '{"message":{"method":"Page.loadEventFired","params":{"timestamp":3369761.458842}},"webview":"A7D8907A1D283AC9EC1B03BC3C786243"}', 'timestamp': 1552406406094}
{'level': 'INFO', 'message': '{"message":{"method":"Page.frameStoppedLoading","params":{"frameId":"A7D8907A1D283AC9EC1B03BC3C786243"}},"webview":"A7D8907A1D283AC9EC1B03BC3C786243"}', 'timestamp': 1552406406094}
{'level': 'INFO', 'message': '{"message":{"method":"Page.domContentEventFired","params":{"timestamp":3369761.45929}},"webview":"A7D8907A1D283AC9EC1B03BC3C786243"}', 'timestamp': 1552406406094}
{'level': 'INFO', 'message': '{"message":{"method":"Page.frameResized","params":{}},"webview":"A7D8907A1D283AC9EC1B03BC3C786243"}', 'timestamp': 1552406406419}
```

I tried using 'true' and 'false' strings in the dictionary as well without any change in the logging captured.

```
caps['perfLoggingPrefs'] = {
    'enableNetwork' : 'true',
    'enablePage' : 'false',
    'enableTimeline' : 'false'
    }
```

Using

- python 3.7
- chromedriver 2.38.552518 (72.0.3626.121)
- python selenium 3.141.0

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you have to pass in `perfLoggingPrefs` as chromeOptions, you can do that through `add_experimental_option()`

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.desired_capabilities import DesiredCapabilities

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.headless = True

caps = DesiredCapabilities.CHROME.copy()
caps['loggingPrefs'] = {
    'browser': 'ALL',
    'performance' : 'ALL',
    }

options.add_experimental_option('perfLoggingPrefs', {
    'enableNetwork' : True,
    'enablePage' : False,
    })

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, desired_capabilities=caps)
driver.get('http://google.com')
perfs = driver.get_log('performance')
for row in perfs:
    print(row)
```

However even when `enablePage` is set to `False`, the `Page` events still show up. On the other hand, filtering does work on `enableNetwork`, so probably a bug in chromedriver.

you can always filter the logs manually, something like:

```
filtered = [p for p in perfs if not json.loads(p["message"])["message"]["method"].startswith('Page')]
```